# SELECT in trigger function in two tables

Tags: postgresql, trigger, datatypes, plpgsql, serialization

My table and trigger in  PostgreSQL 9.4.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
        measurement_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        measurement_size_in_bytes INTEGER NOT NULL
    );    

CREATE TABLE file_headers (
        header_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
        measurement_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        file_header_index_start INTEGER,
        file_header_index_end INTEGER
    );

CREATE TRIGGER measurement_ids AFTER INSERT 
        ON measurements FOR EACH ROW 
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE ins_function('SELECT measurement_id FROM measurements 
        ORDER BY measurement_id desc limit 1;', 1, 666 );
```

where I assumed that the datatype of the SELECT is INTEGER since SERIAL but it is apparently false because I get the error message from this command which starts the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO measurements (measurement_size_in_bytes) VALUES (888);`
```

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "SELECT measurement_id FROM measurements ORDER BY measurement_id desc limit 1;"
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function ins_function() line 10 at assignment
> ```

#### Edit

`ins_function()` and edits based on @a_horse_with_no_name and @Joishi's comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    --
    -- Perform AFTER INSERT operation on file_header by creating rows with new.measurement_id, new.file_header_index_start and new.file_header_index_end.
    --
DECLARE
    measurement_id              INTEGER;
    file_header_index_start     INTEGER;
    file_header_index_end       INTEGER; 
BEGIN     

    SELECT a.measurement_id INTO measurement_id from measurements a ORDER BY measurement_id desc limit 1;
    file_header_index_start := TG_ARGV[0];
    file_header_index_end := TG_ARGV[1]; 

    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO file_headers (measurement_id, file_header_index_start, file_header_index_end)
        VALUES (measurement_id, file_header_index_start, file_header_index_end); 
        RETURN NEW; 
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--
-- Function and trigger on INSERT. 
--
CREATE TRIGGER measurement_ids AFTER INSERT 
    ON measurements FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ins_function(1, 666);
```

I get now no error but the output is wrong: no `INSERT` seen in the table `file_headers` while successfully in the table *measurements*.

#### Output of @ErwinBrandstetter's answer

So I started to think about casting from TEXT to INT but this should be so basic operation, since `TG_ARGV[]` is a datatype of text. One unsuccessful try is `format('SELECT $1.%I', TG_ARGV[0])`.
The `regclass` could work as you describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/54964) in `insaft_function()`

```
SELECT NEW.measurement_id, TG_ARGV[0]::regclass, TG_ARGV[1]::regclass;
```

Why are there no successful INSERTs into the table `file_headers`?

Comment: Show us the definition of the `ins_function()`

Comment: You pass in a `text` (actually `unknown`) to the trigger, it does not match the type defined for `measurement_id` in `ins_function()`.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You are passing a string constant `SELECT ...` to the trigger function, not the result of a SELECT statement. You need to move that select into the trigger function, you can't dynamically pass parameters like that.

Comment: You have a measurement_id defined within your function, and there is also a measurement_id defined within the table you are querying ... thus it is confused as to which one you are wanting it to grab (thus `ambiguous`).  You need to alias your table..  `SELECT a.measurement_id INTO measurement_id FROM measurements a ...`

Comment: Do you have a 2nd, different, trigger on the `file_headers` table that may be changing the value to 100 (instead of 666)?

Comment: If you are not getting another error, but it's simply not inserting data, then the lines of code responsible for the `INSERT` are not being executed (for whatever reason).  Perhaps you accidentally removed a trigger, or perhaps the `IF` if failing within your function..  (The `IF` is not needed, btw, since your trigger is only `AFTER INSERT` .. it would be useful if it was `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE`..)  Regardless - there's not much left here for @a_horse_with_no_name or I to go off of.

Comment: I downvoted this question because you are ***not declaring the version of Postgres in use*** - which is a general nuisance, but outright misleading in this case.

Comment: I suggest to roll back the last edit to de-clutter the question a bit. That last bit was just the result of a trivial syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an **unresolved naming conflict**.

You must be using an **old version of Postgres without declaring it**. Or you are operating with non-default configuration setting.

Here you declare a variable named `measurement_id`:

```
DECLARE
    measurement_id              INTEGER;
```

It's a ***folly*** to use ambiguous variable names to begin with. If you do it anyway, you must *know* what you are doing. I make it a habit to prepend variable names with an underscore unlike column names, like `_measurement_id`.

The later `SELECT` statement is ambiguous:

```
ORDER BY measurement_id
```

This would raise an error message in modern PostgreSQL with default configuration. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html):

> By default, PL/pgSQL will report an error if a name in a SQL statement
> could refer to either a variable or a table column.

And:

> To change this behavior on a system-wide basis, set the configuration
> parameter `plpgsql.variable_conflict` to one of error, use_variable, or
> use_column (where error is the factory default). This parameter
> affects subsequent compilations of statements in PL/pgSQL functions,
> but not statements already compiled in the current session. Because
> changing this setting can cause unexpected changes in the behavior of
> PL/pgSQL functions, it can only be changed by a superuser.

In Postgres older than 9.0 this would be resolved to mean the *variable*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html)

> In such cases you can specify that PL/pgSQL should resolve ambiguous
> references **as the variable** (which is compatible with PL/pgSQL's
> behavior **before PostgreSQL 9.0**)

Bold emphasis mine.
This would result in **arbitrary results**, since the sort order is now undetermined.

#### Audited Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insaft_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _measurement_id          integer;
   _file_header_index_start integer := TG_ARGV[0]::int;
   _file_header_index_end   integer := TG_ARGV[1]::int; 
BEGIN     
   SELECT a.measurement_id
   INTO   _measurement_id
   FROM   measurements a
   ORDER  BY a.measurement_id DESC  -- you had ambiguity here!
   LIMIT  1;

   IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN  -- noise if only used in AFTER INSERT trigger
      INSERT INTO file_headers
             ( measurement_id,  file_header_index_start,  file_header_index_end)
      VALUES (_measurement_id, _file_header_index_start, _file_header_index_end); 
   END IF;

   RETURN NULL;  -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END
$func$;
```

Note the name `insaft_function()`: this is only to be used in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insaft_measurement_ids
AFTER INSERT ON measurements
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function(1, 666);
```

But for the provided setup, you can **radically simplify** the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insaft_function()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN     
   INSERT INTO file_headers 
          (measurement_id, file_header_index_start, file_header_index_end)
   VALUES (NEW.measurement_id, TG_ARGV[0]::int, TG_ARGV[1]::int);

   RETURN NULL;  -- result ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END
$func$;
```

Comment: @Masi: I added the missing cast to `integer` and the semicolon. Tested in pg 9.4 and works for me. Casting to `regclass` would not make sense. Here is an example with proper use of `regclass`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860

Comment: @Masi: `VALUES` or `SELECT`, either method works, I tested both. I just wanted to stay consistent with the first version, no other reason. The error you get is due to missing **parentheses**. `VALUES` requires parentheses.

Comment: @Masi: No measurable difference. `VALUES` can provide multiple rows from given expressions, but not much more, `SELECT` has a whole arsenal of techniques at its fingertips. Basic expressions in the list are evaluated the same.

Comment: Start by reading the [manual on `VALUES` here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html). If you have a new question, start a *new question* with all the necessary details. Comments are not the place.

Comment: I extended the evaluation here http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/107055/69807