# How to cast to int array in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, insert, plpgsql, array, cast

I would like to cast from ARGV[] which is text to int array in PostgreSQL where I marked the pseudocode by *TODO* in the code. 
Code in PostgreSQL 9.4.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
        measurement_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        measurement_size_in_bytes INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE events (
        event_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
        measurement_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        event_index_start INTEGER NOT NULL,
        event_index_end INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insaft_function() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
BEGIN 
  -- TODO Loop until TG_ARGV[0] empty
INSERT INTO events (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end) 
SELECT NEW.measurement_id, TG_ARGV[0]::int[], TG_ARGV[1]::int[];
  -- END TODO
RETURN NULL; -- result ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insaft_measurement_ids
AFTER INSERT ON measurements 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function("{101, 111, 121}", "{101, 111, 121}");
```

which I can start by

```
INSERT INTO measurements (measurement_size_in_bytes) VALUES (888);
```

I know that the mistake is in casting here `TG_ARGV[0]::int[]` into intarray which I would like loop through until the intarray is empty. 
There may exists better way to do such loop inserts.

### ErwinBrandstetter's code output

Code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS measurements, events, file_headers;

CREATE TABLE measurements (
        measurement_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        measurement_size_in_bytes INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE events (
        event_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
        measurement_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        event_index_start INTEGER NOT NULL,
        event_index_end INTEGER NOT NULL
);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insaft_ids ON measurements;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS insaft_function();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insaft_function() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   m int[];
BEGIN 
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY TG_ARGV::int[]
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO events (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end) 
      SELECT NEW.measurement_id, m[1], m[2];  -- Postgres array starts with 1 !
   END LOOP;
   RETURN NULL; -- result ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insaft_ids
AFTER INSERT ON measurements 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function('{{101,201},{201,300}}');
```

Running

```
sudo -u postgres psql detector -c "INSERT INTO measurements (measurement_size_in_bytes) VALUES (77777);"
```

getting

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "{{101,201},{201,300}}"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insaft_function() line 5 at FOREACH over array
```

How can you cast from ARGV[] which is text to int array in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While passing ***integer numbers***, you can either cast the whole array:

```
TG_ARGV::int[]
```

Or you can cast an ***element***, then it must be the element type:

```
TG_ARGV[0]::int
```

I used it that way in my answer to your previous question:

- [SELECT in trigger function in two tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106897/select-in-trigger-function-in-two-tables/106925#106925)

**However**, you are not passing integer numbers, but the text representation of integer arrays: an integer array literal - with illegal syntax, too: values must be enclosed in **single quotes**, double quotes are for identifiers:

```
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function("{101, 111, 121}", "{101, 111, 121}");
```

```
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function('{101, 111, 121}', '{101, 111, 121}');
```

Since you are not passing `integer` but integer array literals, you cannot do either in your code. Consider this (using a clearer example with distinct numbers):

```
SELECT (ARRAY['{101, 111, 121}', '{201, 211, 221}'])[1]::int[];
SELECT (ARRAY['{101, 111, 121}', '{201, 211, 221}'])::text[];
SELECT (ARRAY['{101, 111, 121}'::int[], '{201, 211, 221}'])::int[];
SELECT (ARRAY['{101, 111, 121}'::int[], '{201, 211, 221}'])[1][1];
SELECT (ARRAY['{{101, 111, 121},{201, 211, 221}}'])[1];
SELECT (ARRAY['{{101, 111, 121},{201, 211, 221}}'])[1]::int[];
```

[@Chris provided more for that.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107087/3684)

#### Solution for your function

I suggest you *either* pass all integer numbers *or* a 2-dimensional array literal. Demonstrating code for the *latter*:

```
'{{101,111,121},{201,211,221}}'
```

Or rather (the array pivoted, based on my educated guess):

```
'{{101,201},{111,211},{121,221}}'
```

So, this is *one* parameter:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insaft_function('{{101,201},{111,211},{121,221}}');
```

As for the loop, use `FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY`. See:

- [Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784986/939860)

Function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insaft_function() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   m int[];
BEGIN 
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY TG_ARGV[0]::int[]  -- reference 1st param
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO events (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end) 
      SELECT NEW.measurement_id, m[1], m[2];  -- Postgres array starts with 1 !
   END LOOP;
   RETURN NULL; -- result ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END 
$func$;
```

But I have my suspicions there might be a simpler overall approach. This only makes sense if you have many tables that need the same trigger, just with different integer numbers ...

Comment: @Masi: I actually tested the function I provided and it works for me. Are you aware that `int` denotes the integer type and **`int[]`** denotes an array of integer? Some basics here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12414884/939860

Comment: @Masi: Sorry, it must be `TG_ARGV` **`[0]`** `::int[]`. I tested two versions (`either pass all integer numbers or a 2-dimensional array literal`) and mixed trigger and function definition from both by accident. The syntax  `TG_ARGV::int[]` only works "all integer numbers" - *multiple* parameters like: `insaft_function(101,201,201,300)`. Since you are passing a text literal for a (2-dimentional) int array as *one* parameter, you must refer to `TG_ARGV[0]`. I adapted the code above.

Comment: `events.event_index_start` and `events.event_index_end` must be defined as `bigint` accordingly.

Comment: Yes, so use `bigint` if `unsigned int` but here `signed int` so keep to use just the `int`. Followup thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533496/to-convert-from-python-arrays-to-postgresql-quickly

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you're on the right track, if I'm understanding your question clearly (which I'm not sure that I am. :P )

To me, it looks like you simply need a `DECLARE` block, where you are declaring variable values which will persist throughout the function block.

## Add `DECLARE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insaft_function() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
DECLARE
myarray_0 int[] := TG_ARGV[0]::int[]
myarray_1 int[] := TG_ARGV[1]::int[]
$func$
BEGIN 
-- TODO Loop until myarray_0 empty
-- Decide what you really want to do here!!
-- Is it a parallel loop through myarray_0 and myarray_1, or a Cartesian, or...
-- END TODO
RETURN NULL; -- result ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You've got the casting right, but if you want to loop through them easily in the function, you just need to do it upfront with a `DECLARE` block.

We can leave the debate for another time, however, if this is the best approach for achieving the inserts you are hoping to do...