# PostgreSQL function incorrectly returns 0 rows

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, parameter

I'm learning how to create functions in Postgres. Below is a function I'm trying to get to return two numbers, but no matter what I try it always returns 0 rows.

Does anyone have any idea how I could get this function to work?

In the sections containing "blah blah blah" is my original query containing numerous tables that I'm joining together and some constraints I'm setting in the where section.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "testFunction10"( integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (
epc bigint,
stc bigint)
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY select coutns.epc, coutns.stc

from
((select count(DISTINCT Association.rank) as epc, count(DISTINCT
oldest_pricing."startTime") as stc

from blah blah blah

left join balh blah blah and title_id = $1) -- input goes in here

left join blah blah blah

left join blah blah blah

where blah blah blah))coutns;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example call:

```
select * from "testFunction10"(123);
```

Returns 0 rows.

Comment: Apparently somewhere in your "blah blah blah" you have a condition that makes the query not return any rows. You need to change the "blah blah" to a condition that returns the correct result

Comment: No because when I run the query inside the function on its own I get results; it's only when I use it in the function that it returns nothing

Comment: This is a non reproducible error. Provide with code that reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: I'm unable to share my query with you, but like I said the blah blah blah part works on its own as a query, but when I include in the function it doesn't return the same result.

Comment: I guess why question is can I use one of my existing queries that joins many different tables together in a function where the input of the function pipes in a unique id to the query and then returns to me the result?

Comment: Why are there double parentheses `((` and `))`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original poster refuses to share what the actual problem is....

Answer (score 1):

Just an educated guess while you do not disclose your complete function code.

If the same query returns two rows outside the function body, but 0 rows if you wrap it into this function, the most likely reason is a **naming conflict** between one of the `OUT` parameters `epc` or `stc` with column names in one of your `JOIN` or `WHERE` conditions. Since these parameters are NULL by default (until assigned), any condition like `epc = anything` would evaluate to NULL and eliminate all rows fro the result.

Yes, the two column names in the `RETURNS` clause are `OUT` parameter names and visible inside every SQL query inside the function body:

```
RETURNS TABLE (epc bigint, stc bigint) AS ...
```

It's therefore unwise to define `OUT` parameter names that match column names and introduce a naming conflict this way. You might use some prefix that's never used for column names like `_epc` to defend against it.

If you need conflicting names, be sure to **table-qualify conflicting column names in SQL queries at all times**.

Related:

- [SELECT in trigger function in two tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106897/select-in-trigger-function-in-two-tables/106925#106925)
- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105831/naming-conflict-between-function-parameter-and-result-of-join-with-using-clause)